# In C# Visual Studio is it possible to take a memory snapshot once app uses set amount of memory?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, memory-leaks

I have a c# web crawler I'm trying to debug some memory issues with.

What appears to be happening is occasionally it will use x10-40 the amount of memory it typically does and then either crash as the system runs out of memory OR the task will complete and the GC will just free the memory and the app will continue as normal. Until the next mass memory usage.

In VS 2017 community edition is it possible to trigger a memory snapshot once a certain amount of memory is in use?

As its very time consuming sitting here waiting for a memory leak when I have no idea what the cause is...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it exist in Visual Studio. You can do such thing with dotMemory (Memory Profiler) from Jetbrains.